# What is gVim render stack?

Tags: gvim

I would like to know which technology/ies are used to display gVim windows and fonts on graphical environments (Windows, Mac, Linux and BSD).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The source code for each is available, as are the maintainers—you may be able to find out that way. If you do, feel free to self-answer with reference back to the information!